# Build failed at Cmake while building native module

Tags: android-studio, cmake, apache-cordova

I am building a cordova project which requires cmake for building the native modules for android. Everything was working well and the build was successful but after upgrading the cmake to 3.10.2 on android studio I am getting this error.

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':generateJsonModelDebug'.
> Error occurred while communicating with CMake server. Check log /home/hottab/Documents/Cordovaapps/pos/platforms/android/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/cmake_server_log.txt for additional information.
```

**cmake_server_log.txt**

```
CMAKE SERVER: 

CMAKE SERVER: [== "CMake Server" ==[

CMAKE SERVER: {"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

CMAKE SERVER: ]== "CMake Server" ==]
```

I tried to downgrade it to 3.6.0 ,3.6.2 and 3.6.3 but the problem persisted. My previous version that I checked on android studio was 3.6.4111459 . When I am downloading cmake via android studio its currently downloading 3.10.2. Is there any way that this problem can be solved. any help will be deeply appreciated. I have seen other questions but none of the method worked.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the installed Cmake and then installing cmake 3.6.4111459 via Android_Studio solved the issue. But build was still failing due to sync error on android 3.3 , downgrading to 3.2.1 solved the issue . To solve the issue of sync failure on android 3.3 you have to install ninja and configure the permission request To make it work. Hope that helps